# How can I sort the a list of strings which contain date as substring

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Below is my list,

```
['pending/', 'pending/2021-08-01/', 'pending/2021-06-01/', 'pending/2021-06-18/']
```

And I need to sort the list and filter it to a below format. Please suggest a quicker way to achieve it

```
['pending/2021-06-01/', 'pending/2021-06-18/', 'pending/2021-08-01/']
```

Comment: Quicker than *what*? What code do you have that is insufficiently performant? Note: For a `list` this small, it hardly matters what you do; it'll take no time at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your format is fixed and always starts with "pending" you can use the normal `sorted` function and count the `/` in a list comprehension.

```py
>>> values = ['pending/', 'pending/2021-08-01/', 'pending/2021-06-01/', 'pending/2021-06-18/']
>>> sorted(x for x in values if x.count('/') == 2)
['pending/2021-06-01/', 'pending/2021-06-18/', 'pending/2021-08-01/']
```

Comment: May as well filter first, then sort, and save sort work for values you don't want anyway: `sorted(x for x in values if x.count('/') == 2)` (or add square brackets to make it a listcomp instead of a genexpr, which is likely to be slightly faster despite the higher peak memory usage, due to runtime inefficiencies in genexprs).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Good point, I applied this in my post.